# Enzyme , Jest - Need some help on testing ReactJs Components (Axios)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I have a problem.
I am trying to run my first time in my life testing my code using ENZYME / JEST. I have a function that makes a POST request using AXIOS and I want to generate a test code snippet to check if the request has been sent and if there is an answer. And if the answer contains data in the array.
This is my "Search.jsx"

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Suggestions from "../components/suggestions";
let API="http://localhost:5000"


class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    results: []
  };

  redirectPage = query => {
    window.open(`https://www.bing.com/search?q=${query}`)
  };

  getInfo = query => {
    axios.post(API, { query: query }).then(({ data }) => {

      this.setState({
        results: data
      });
    });
  };

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        query: this.search.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            this.getInfo(this.state.query);
          }
        } else {
          this.setState({
            results: []
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
          <input
          placeholder="Search for..."
          ref={input => (this.search = input)}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <Suggestions results={this.state.results} redirectPage={this.redirectPage} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

and is test that i copy from here and i need help to make it work for me ):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Search from './search';

jest.mock('axios', () => {
  const exampleArticles = [
    { title: 'test article', url: 'test url' }
  ];
  
  return {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(exampleArticles)),
  };
});

const axios = require('axios');

it('fetch articles on #getInfo', () => {
  const search = shallow(<Search />);
  search
    .instance()
    .componentDidMount()
    .then(() => {
      expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('articles_url');
      expect(search.state()).toHaveProperty('articles', [
        { title: 'test article', url: 'test url' }
      ]);
      done();
    });
});
```

Appreciate who can help me for my first time.

Comment: And what have you tried to make the code work? What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Is there any error?